# Apple pushnotification

Tags: php, linux, ssl, push-notification

I have a PHP script located in path like `/var/www/vhosts/hostname/httpdocs/webservices`, I have both PHP script and `.pem` files there, and I have called the `.pem` file in the script properly, but still when I run the script , I don't get push notification , instead i get warnings such as:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Unable to set local cert chain file `ck_push_test.pem'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in /var/www/vhosts/ipartyapps.com/httpdocs/webservices/testPush.php on line 12

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: failed to create an SSL handle in /var/www/vhosts/ipartyapps.com/httpdocs/webservices/testPush.php on line 12

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/vhosts/ipartyapps.com/httpdocs/webservices/testPush.php on line 12

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /var/www/vhosts/ipartyapps.com/httpdocs/webservices/testPush.php on line 12
Failed to connect 0
```

I double checked everything path, permissions and owner/group of both script and `.pem` files, still not getting push notification.

Comment: This sounds like more than just checking some local permissions though: "Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer"

Comment: can you enlighten me about what is meant by "cafile/capath" settings & where to look for them or how to change them ?

Comment: @VIVEK nope, sorry... Seems to be related to OpenSSL. This question may be better off on serverfault.com, voting to migrate there.

Comment: @Pekka: agree with the 'off-topic,' but perhaps for [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @David hmmm, I think the folks on Serverfault are much better suited to fix the underlying certificate problem. It's likely to be sorted on the Linux command line

Comment: @Pekka, you could well be right, my thought of Webmasters was only due to the faq-like page the off-topic dialog links to :)

Comment: Ok David & Pekka, i have posted this issue to webmasters also, can anybody please reply or tell anybody else you know, to reply ?

Comment: My question just got migrated back to stackoverflow & closed. Please anybody help me out on this issue, as it's urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are getting the error because you are unintentionally trying to find the .pem file in the directory you are running the script from rather than finding it relative to the .php script file.

i.e. using

```
$location = "file.pem";
```

rather than

```
$location = dirname(__FILE__)."/file.pem";
```

Can you post your code so we can check it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you are using the correct pem file ? (the one that has concatenated both private key and certificate? )

Open you pem file and check whether it have certificate and private key like below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<certificate details>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key>
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

mine was fixed once i moved the correct pem file